# PHP function for permutations without repetition

Tags: php, for-loop, combinations, permutation, repeat

I am looking for a php function that provides me all the possible combinations between 1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9 numbers without repetitions in groups of 3 digits. For example: 123, 456, 789, 124, 125...
this is my code so far:

```
<?php
for($a=1;$a<10;$a++){
    for($b=1;$b<10;$b++){
          for($c=1;$c<10;$c++){
                echo $a.$b.$c.", ";
              }
           }
      }
?>
```

but in this one, there are repetitions. Anyone can help me to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: well yeah, for `$b` you're not skipping over `if($b==$a)`, and for `$c` you're not checking against both `$a` and `$b`. If you don't want duplicates, check for duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
for($a=1;$a<10;$a++){
    for($b=1; $b<10;$b++){
        if($b == $a){ continue; }
        for($c=1; $c<10 ;$c++){
            if($c == $a || $c == $b){ continue; }
            echo $a.$b.$c.", ";
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `if($c == $a || $c == $b){ continue; }`

Comment: thanks dudes!
and specially thanks @Mike_'Pomax'_Kamermans, you lead me to the solution by myself. 
and whoever downvoted me need to know that he was very mean.

Comment: @dream333r You should post an answer then as to your solution. Stack does let you do that, plus you can even accept your own answer when Stack lets you to. I did not downvote btw.